# Excel Formula, Count of days from current date to last weekday of previous month

Tags: microsoft-excel

I cant seem to get `workday` to work for this.

My current date is in cell D2. `28/09/2018`

I would expect to get the last month last weekday which would be `31/08/2018`. and count the days between them.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the last weekday in the previous month:

```
=WORKDAY(EOMONTH(D2,-1)+1,-1)
```

To get the number of days between the two:

```
=DATEDIF(WORKDAY(EOMONTH(D2,-1)+1,-1),D2,"d")
```

TO get the number of weekdays between the two:

```
=NETWORKDAYS(WORKDAY(EOMONTH(D2,-1)+1,-1),D2,1)
```